# How an os.Signal channel is handled internally in Go?

Tags: go, unix, signals

When having the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

func main() {
    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sig)
    <-sig
}
```

Runs without problem, of course, blocking until you send a signal that interrupts the program.

But:

```golang
package main

func main() {
    sig := make(chan int, 1)
    <-sig
}
```

throws this error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /home/user/project/src/main.go:5 +0x4d
exit status 2
```

While I understand why reading from the `int` channel causes a deadlock, I have only a suspicion
that the `os.Signal` doesn't because its channel can suffer writes from "the outside" as, well,
it handles signals and they come from outside the program.

Is my suspicion somewhat correct? If so, how the runtime handles this differently from other channel types?

Thank you!

Comment: The actual signal handling is OS specific and implemented in the runtime. Handling of the channel, however, is no different from any other channel. Calling Notify launches a goroutine that will eventually send an os.Signal value on the channel.

Comment: Try your first program without  `signal.Notify(sig)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a deadlock because try to receive message from channel but no other goroutine running that is no sender exists. In the same time call to `signal.Notify` starts `watchSignalLoop()` goroutine in background  and you can  verify implementation details here https://golang.org/src/os/signal/signal.go.

Channels don't care about element type unless your element type is larger than 64kB (strictly speaking, there are other nuances, please check the implementation).

Don't guess about how runtime works, make researches about it. For example, you can check what happens when you call `make(chan int)`. You can do `go tool compile -S main.go | grep main.go:line of make chan` and check which function is called from runtime package. Then just jump to this file and invest your time to understand the implementation. You will see that implementation of channels is thin and straightforward comparing to other things

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Channels don't care about element type unless your element type is less than 64kB" Do you have a source for that statement? Pretty much all element types are smaller than 64kB in practice.

Comment: @Peter https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/align.go#L301 , https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/chan.go#L75

Comment: That's what I thought. There's a difference if the type is *larger* than 64k, not smaller. I took the liberty to correct the answer.